# Powershell colored directory listing is incorrect with format-wide

Tags: powershell, colors, directory

I got this colored dir script from http://tasteofpowershell.blogspot.com/2009/02/get-childitem-dir-results-color-coded.html:

```
function ls {
  $regex_opts = ([System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::IgnoreCase -bor [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Compiled)

  $fore = $Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor
  $compressed = New-Object System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex('\.(zip|tar|gz|rar)$', $regex_opts)
  $executable = New-Object System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex('\.(exe|bat|cmd|ps1|psm1|vbs|rb|reg|dll|o|lib)$', $regex_opts)
  $executable = New-Object System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex('\.(exe|bat|cmd|ps1|psm1|vbs|rb|reg|dll|o|lib)$', $regex_opts)
  $source = New-Object System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex('\.(py|pl|cs|rb|h|cpp)$', $regex_opts)
  $text = New-Object System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex('\.(txt|cfg|conf|ini|csv|log|xml)$', $regex_opts)

  Invoke-Expression ("Get-ChildItem $args") |
    %{
      if ($_.GetType().Name -eq 'DirectoryInfo') {
        $Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = 'DarkCyan'
        $_
        $Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = $fore
      } elseif ($compressed.IsMatch($_.Name)) {
        $Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = 'Yellow'
        $_
        $Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = $fore
      } elseif ($executable.IsMatch($_.Name)) {
        $Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = 'Red'
        $_
        $Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = $fore
      } elseif ($text.IsMatch($_.Name)) {
        $Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = 'Green'
        $_
        $Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = $fore
      } elseif ($source.IsMatch($_.Name)) {
        $Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = 'Cyan'
        $_
        $Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = $fore
      } else {
        $_
      }
    }
}
```

It works great, but I most of the time I want only the file names, in wide format. So after the invoke-expression call, I added

```
  Invoke-Expression ("Get-ChildItem $args") |
    %{
      if ($_.GetType().Name -eq 'DirectoryInfo') {
  :
  :
  :
        $_
      }
    } | format-wide -property Name
}
```

Now I have a bug. Only the colour of the second column is correct; the first item in each column takes the colour of the item in the second column. For example, if I have

```
> ls

Directory     Program.exe
```

Then both Directory and Program.exe will be red, even though Directory is supposed to be DarkCyan. How can I correct this?

Comment: This is a really cool script :D - I tried to run the script using powershell_ise.exe. It colors the output while executing (I put breakpoints) but when it finishes executing the colors don't persist. Do you know why? I'm using PowerShell 2.0 (Windows 7). How would you call this script from within PowerShell? Let's say I save a file named color.ps1 inside my Desktop folder. Then I open PowserShell, navigate to the folder and type .\color.ps1. Nothing happens. What am I missing to make this script run from within PowerShell?

Comment: I'm no expert, but I think it just defines a function called `ls`. After running the script, you actually have to run the function via `ls`. You may have to source color.ps1 with `. .\color.ps1`.

Comment: I call the ls function after loading color.ps1 and the output is still uncolored.

Comment: Make sure you are dot sourcing the file `. .\color.ps1` and then execute Get-ChildItemColor and you should get colored output.

Comment: Thanks Nathan and Keith. Now I got the colored output. Really cool this thing. I was using only `.\color.ps1`. When I did `. .\color.ps1` the thing worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than twiddling the foreground/background colors of the host in between displaying text to the screen, why don't you use Write-Host which gives you a bit more control over the displayed text (you can control when newlines are output) e.g.:

```
$_ | Out-String -stream | Write-Host -Fore Red
```

And for the wide listing use, you will need to handle the column formatting yourself unless you want to update the format data XML for the DirectoryInfo/FileInfo types.  If you don't want to do that, then you can write out each name - padded out appropriately - with the desired color.  On the last column, set the -NoNewLine param to $false:

```
$width =  $host.UI.RawUI.WindowSize.Width
$cols = 3   
ls | % {$i=0; $pad = [int]($width/$cols) - 1} `
       {$nnl = ++$i % $cols -ne 0; `
        Write-Host ("{0,-$pad}" -f $_) -Fore Green -NoNewLine:$nnl}
```

Comment: This works great _unless_ $pad is not an integer (and 80/3 - 1 is not). I edited your example to include an int conversion.

Comment: Thx.  To really flesh it out you should also find the max length of each name and then determine how many columns you can display rather than hardcoding it to 3.  :-)

Comment: could you please tell me what I need to do so that this script can color my output inside PowerShell? Take a look at my comment in the question.

Comment: i try the change that you say of write-host, but then every item is printed as a new ls, ie: one line for the path, then other line with the headers and then the line that i really want, how do you apply correctly the changes?

Comment: There is only one problem with this - by using write-host, the result is converted to strings and output as only text, whereas the standard get-childitem outputs an object, which is more useful for piping, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Just thought I would point you to this question I posted which outputs linux style colored output and format in columns correctly. [How to write a list sorted lexicographically in a grid listed by column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126409/how-to-write-a-list-sorted-lexicographically-in-a-grid-listed-by-column)