# How to write a list sorted lexicographically in a grid listed by column?

Tags: powershell, directory, get-childitem

I have the result of `Get-ChildItem`, and I want to iterate over these, and display their names. By default if I simply use `Write-Host` then I get it listed out along the row like this:

```
PerfLogs  Program Files  Program Files (x86)  Python31  Temp  Users  Windows
```

However, say that I know I want it split into x columns, I want the output like this instead:

```
PerfLogs                  Python31     Windows
Program Files             Temp
Program Files (x86)       Users
```

As you can see, it lists it down the columns first, and then across.

Any idea how to get output like that?  Ideally it would use the most # of columns as can fit on screen with the Name aligned to the left in each column.

UPDATE: thanks to Roman, I can now have my linux style 'ls' output with directory colors. Building off his updated script I have:

```
function color-ls
{
    dir $args | Format-High -Print {    
        $item = $args
        $fore = $host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor        
        $host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = .{     
            if ($item[1].psIsContainer) {'Blue'}
            elseif ($item[1].Extension -match '\.(exe|bat|cmd|ps1|psm1|vbs|rb|reg|dll|o|lib)') {'Red'}
            elseif ($item[1].Extension -match '\.(zip|tar|gz|rar)') {'Yellow'}
            elseif ($item[1].Extension -match '\.(py|pl|cs|rb|h|cpp)') {'Cyan'}
            elseif ($item[1].Extension -match '\.(txt|cfg|conf|ini|csv|log|xml)') {'Green'}
            else {$fore}
        }
        write-host $args[0] -NoNewLine
        $host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = $fore
    }
}
```

Output:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2809/lscolor.png

Comment: I am glad that you reused the updated script exactly in a way it was designed for. Thank you for the inspiring idea. It would be nice if PowerShell has this built-in, I have submitted the suggestion:
https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/620452/format-wide-add-an-option-to-output-by-columns

Comment: Where do I put `Format-High.ps1`? I've tried `C:\Users\X\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Scripts\Format-High.ps1` and also in the same dir as my profile containing `color-ls` which is `C:\Users\X\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` but I get the error `The term 'Format-High.ps1' is not recognized`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It’s an interesting idea and task.

UPDATE: the updated script contains a few fixes and improvements. It also allows to customize the output in several ways.  See examples in the script comments.

Script Format-High.ps1:

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Formats input by columns using maximum suitable column number.

.DESCRIPTION
    Format-High prints the specified property, expression, or string
    representation of input objects filling the table by columns.

    It is named in contrast to Format-Wide which prints by rows.

.EXAMPLE
    # just items
    ls c:\windows | Format-High

    # ditto in colors based on PSIsContainer
    ls c:\windows | Format-High -Print {$c = if ($args[1].PSIsContainer) {'yellow'} else {'white'}; Write-Host $args[0] -ForegroundColor $c -NoNewline}

    # just processes, not good
    ps | Format-High

    # process names, much better
    ps | Format-High Name

    # custom expression and width
    ps | Format-High {$_.Name + ':' + $_.WS} 70

    # process names in colors based on working sets
    ps | Format-High Name 70 {$c = if ($args[1].WS -gt 10mb) {'red'} else {'green'}; Write-Host $args[0] -ForegroundColor $c -NoNewline}
#>

param
(
    [object]$Property,
    [int]$Width = $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowSize.Width - 1,
    [scriptblock]$Print = { Write-Host $args[0] -NoNewline },
    [object[]]$InputObject
)

# process the input, get strings to format
if ($InputObject -eq $null) { $InputObject = @($input) }
if ($Property -is [string]) { $strings = $InputObject | Select-Object -ExpandProperty $Property }
elseif ($Property -is [scriptblock]) { $strings = $InputObject | ForEach-Object $Property }
else { $strings = $InputObject }
$strings = @(foreach($_ in $strings) { "$_" })

# pass 1: find the maximum column number
$nbest = 1
$bestwidths = @($Width)
for($ncolumn = 2; ; ++$ncolumn) {
    $nrow = [Math]::Ceiling($strings.Count / $ncolumn)
    $widths = @(
        for($s = 0; $s -lt $strings.Count; $s += $nrow) {
            $e = [Math]::Min($strings.Count, $s + $nrow)
            ($strings[$s .. ($e - 1)] | Measure-Object -Maximum Length).Maximum + 1
        }
    )
    if (($widths | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum -gt $Width) {
        break
    }
    $bestwidths = $widths
    $nbest = $ncolumn
    if ($nrow -le 1) {
        break
    }
}

# pass 2: print strings
$nrow = [Math]::Ceiling($strings.Count / $nbest)
for($r = 0; $r -lt $nrow; ++$r) {
    for($c = 0; $c -lt $nbest; ++$c) {
        $i = $c * $nrow + $r
        if ($i -lt $strings.Count) {
            & $Print ($strings[$i].PadRight($bestwidths[$c])) $InputObject[$i]
        }
    }
    & $Print "`r`n"
}
```

Comment: Agreed on the sorting, this is damn good. I am just learning powershell, can you point me to what the .{} does in $widths = .{} ?

Comment: after the summation of the widths, it should be $bestwidths = ($widths) .. if there is only one file it throws an exception.

Comment: `.{}` is the *dot* operator (invoke in the current scope) + the script block being invoked by it. But in this case there is a better construct `@()` which also fixes the bug that you noticed. I will update the code soon (there are other minor flaws, too).

Comment: Hi Roman. Any idea why this hangs when there are no files in the directory at all ?

Comment: A bug. I've updated the code: replaced `if ($nrow -eq 1)` with `if ($nrow -le 1)`.