# Is it possible to get colour highlighting with the Powershell dir command

Tags: powershell

On the Mac or Linux terminal it is possible to get colour listings of directory contents; files are a different colour from folders, for instance (ignoring the quotes used for Stackoverflow colouration):

```
>ls
README.md 'src' 'tests' .gitignore
```

Is it possible to similarly color highlight the output of the `Get-ChildItem` command in Powershell?

Comment: Not right out of the box but with a little effort it is possible. See these two questions/answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126409/how-to-write-a-list-sorted-lexicographically-in-a-grid-listed-by-column http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420731/powershell-colored-directory-listing-is-incorrect-with-format-wide

Comment: You probably wanted the answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406434/powershell-properly-coloring-get-childitem-output-once-and-for-all

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is quite easy to do.

```
$List = gci –path 'C:\yourpathhere\' -rec
foreach ($item in $List) {
    if ($item.PSIsContainer) {
        write-host $item.Name -foregroundcolor "magenta" 
    } else {
        write-host $item.Name -foregroundcolor "yellow"
    }
}
```