# How to define folder colors in powershell?

Tags: powershell

> Can put colors in directory like this image?

[image: Console color settings]

[devblogs.microsoft](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/new-experimental-console-features/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Powershell: Properly coloring Get-Childitem output once and for all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406434/powershell-properly-coloring-get-childitem-output-once-and-for-all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I found, Thanks Jawad

`Install-Module PSColor`and 
add `Import-Module PSColor` to `$PROFILE`

https://github.com/Davlind/PSColor