# PowerShell New-CommandWrapper : Supply values for the following parameters

Tags: powershell

I mean to colorize the output of `ls`.
I checked [Powershell: Properly coloring Get-Childitem output once and for all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406434/powershell-properly-coloring-get-childitem-output-once-and-for-all).

The two options appear to be:

1. Use `New-CommandWrapper`, as advocated in the OP and the answer by Jon Z.
2. Use module `PSColor`.

I obtained the code for `New-CommandWrapper` from the OP (it is the same as [provided by O'Reilly](https://resources.oreilly.com/examples/0636920024132/raw/master/New-CommandWrapper.ps1?inline=false)), placed it in file `New-CommandWrapper.ps1`, and dot source it in my `profile.ps1`.
Now when I open a new session I get

```
cmdlet New-CommandWrapper.ps1 at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Name:
```

**Is this ok? If so, what should I enter? Or how do I fix this?**
(I am certain the issue is quite simple).

**Note**: I couldn't make `PSColor` work, and this is possibly worth a another question.
As mentioned in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406434/powershell-properly-coloring-get-childitem-output-once-and-for-all#comment111394603_30788506), after importing the module, (almost?) any cmdlet outputs

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: command
En línea: 39 Carácter: 9
+         $steppablePipeline.Begin($PSCmdlet)
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`
```

---

**EDIT**:
With the modification suggested by Thomas, the problem changed.
Now I get the same `Value cannot be null.` error.
I would like to conclude that his suggestion is right, and I solved one of the many chained problems I had... but I cannot be sure.

Comment: Add `function New-CommandWrapper {` on the first line of the script and `}` on the last line

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - The issue went away with this modification. But I still couldn't make dir colors work. `ls` gives now the same `Value cannot be null.` error (produced by a different command than the cae of the OP, surely... how can I tell this?).

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - Besides, why would the instructions for using `New-CommandWrapper` not detail this? Or did I miss it?

Comment: Well, without the modification you'd just use the script file directly, like `.\path\to\New-CommandWrapper.ps1 Command-Name -AddParameter @{ Param = {...} }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `New-CommandWrapper` is packaged as a *script*, rather than as a function, so you'll need to edit the script file slightly if you want to dot-source it:

1. Insert `function New-CommandWrapper {` at the very top of `New-CommandWrapper.ps1`
2. Add an `}` on the very last line

Now you can dot-source it (from your profile if need be) and use the example given in the linked answer:

```
PS C:\> . .\path\to\New-CommandWrapper.ps1
PS C:\> New-CommandWrapper Out-Default `
>>>    -Process {
>>>        if(($_ -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]) -or ($_ -is [System.IO.FileInfo]))
>>>        {if(-not ($notfirst)) {
>>>           Write-Host "    Directory: $(pwd)`n"           
>>>           Write-Host "Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name"
>>>           Write-Host "----                -------------     ------ ----"
>>>           $notfirst=$true
>>>           }
>>>           if ($_ -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]) {
>>>           Write-host ("{0,-7} {1,25} {2,10} {3}" -f $_.mode, ([String]::Format("{0,10}  {1,8}", $_.LastWriteTime.ToString("d"), $_.LastWriteTime.ToString("t"))), $_.length, $_.name) -foregroundcolor "yellow" }
>>>           else {
>>>           Write-host ("{0,-7} {1,25} {2,10} {3}" -f $_.mode, ([String]::Format("{0,10}  {1,8}", $_.LastWriteTime.ToString("d"), $_.LastWriteTime.ToString("t"))), $_.length, $_.name) -foregroundcolor "green" }
>>>           $_ = $null
>>>        }
>>>}
```

Comment: This works. After some debugging, I found the culprit for all the pain:
I had added at the top of my `profile.ps1` the code suggested at the top of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62838107/2707864).
It worked mostly ok.
But in some cases (as in this case, with both methods for colorizing `dir` output), by "interfering" with other commands, it was producing the `Value cannot be null.` error.
Moreover, if I added that code below the scripts for colorizing `dir` output, it did not produce an error upon `dir`, but output was simply white.