# PowerShell debug execution

Tags: powershell, debugging, traceback

Trying to use module `PSColor`, I get the error

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: command
En línea: 39 Carácter: 9
+         $steppablePipeline.Begin($PSCmdlet)
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`
```

as mentioned in
[PowerShell New-CommandWrapper : Supply values for the following parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62993334/powershell-new-commandwrapper-supply-values-for-the-following-parameters)

**How can I trace execution of commands, to find the culprit and fix the problem?**

What I tried:

1. I added [`Set-PSDebug -Trace 2 -Strict`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-psdebug) at the top of my `profile.ps1`.
2. Enabled line `Import-Module PSColor` in `profile.ps1` (method 2 in question [PowerShell New-CommandWrapper : Supply values for the following parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62993334/powershell-new-commandwrapper-supply-values-for-the-following-parameters) and the most voted answer in [Powershell: Properly coloring Get-Childitem output once and for all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406434/powershell-properly-coloring-get-childitem-output-once-and-for-all)).

Now during startup I get a lot of debugging info.
The output I get with my first command is

```
> cd .\utils\
DEBUG:    7+  >>>> {
DEBUG:     ! CALL function '<ScriptBlock><Begin>'
DEBUG:   13+          >>>> $foreachObject = $executionContext.InvokeCommand.GetCmdlet(
DEBUG:     ! SET $foreachObject = 'ForEach-Object'.
DEBUG:   16+          >>>> $wrappedCmd = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.GetCommand(
DEBUG:     ! SET $wrappedCmd = 'Out-Default-01e1d80299c048d787db8ef5fe8bb78c'.
DEBUG:   22+          >>>> $targetParameters = @{}
DEBUG:     ! SET $targetParameters = 'System.Collections.Hashtable'.
DEBUG:   23+          >>>> $PSBoundParameters.GetEnumerator() |
DEBUG:   32+          >>>> $newPipeline = { & $wrappedCmd @targetParameters }
DEBUG:     ! SET $newPipeline = ' & $wrappedCmd @targetParameters '.
DEBUG:   33+          >>>> $finalPipeline = $newPipeline.ToString()
DEBUG:     ! SET $finalPipeline = ' & $wrappedCmd @targetParameters '.
DEBUG:   37+          >>>> $steppablePipeline = [ScriptBlock]::Create(
DEBUG:     ! SET $steppablePipeline = 'System.Management.Automation.SteppablePipel...'.
DEBUG:   39+          >>>> $steppablePipeline.Begin($PSCmdlet)
DEBUG:   41+          >>>> throw
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: command
En línea: 39 Carácter: 9
+         $steppablePipeline.Begin($PSCmdlet)
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

But:

1. I cannot infer from here the complete chain of commands starting from my `cd ...`
2. File names are not shown.

So I cannot progress any further.
The fact that I am a novice in PS certainly plays a significant role here.

---

**Motivation for the question**:

I mean to colorize the output of `ls`.
I checked [Powershell: Properly coloring Get-Childitem output once and for all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406434/powershell-properly-coloring-get-childitem-output-once-and-for-all).

The two options appear to be:

1. Use `New-CommandWrapper`, as advocated in the OP and the answer by Jon Z.
2. Use module `PSColor`.

Trying both options, I end up in an alley with the error above.

---

**Related**:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/180133/how-can-i-track-executed-powershell-commands-within-a-network . I was helped by this.

Comment: This is not an answer for the question, but I found the culprit for all the pain:
I had added at the top of my `profile.ps1` the code suggested at the top of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62838107/2707864).
It worked mostly ok.
But in some cases, by "interfering" with other commands, it was producing the `Value cannot be null.` error.
Moreover, if I added that code below the scripts for colorizing `dir` output, it did not produce an error upon `dir`, but output was simply white.