# How do I set color in powershell for file listing

Tags: .net, powershell

I rather like ls's ability to colorize its listing to highlight different file types.  So I've created my own ps1xml file and have been tweaking the format for the FileSystemTypes.  Great fun and I haven't hurt myself too badly yet!

I've been able to change the contents and formatting of a field (for example, making the LastModifiedTime column a little more to my liking), but I don't know how to change the color.  Is this possible?  I'm a little new to PowerShell and there's a lot there, so I might well be missing something obvious.

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are some links that discuss about the coloring of `get-childitem` output.

[Get-ChildItem (dir) Results Color-Coded by Type](http://tasteofpowershell.blogspot.com/2009/02/get-childitem-dir-results-color-coded.html)
[How to write a list sorted lexicographically in a grid listed by column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126409/how-to-write-a-list-sorted-lexicographically-in-a-grid-listed-by-column)
[Powershell colored directory listing is incorrect with format-wide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420731/powershell-colored-directory-listing-is-incorrect-with-format-wide)